# Old domain assigned to new site - looks good to me, client claims he and friends still see old site

Tags: dns

In other words - they got a new website and used the domain that was assigned to the old site.
When I google it or yahoo or bing it, on the three browsers on my Mac, I find the new website.

I think he's saying the old website still comes up. It's been a month. they're using I.E. not sure what version. He claims they're seeing the old site on pc's that have never before been used to view the old site, so the cache is not an issue.

I don't see how this is possible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

He may be having the old website's IP address cached. Ask the client to open command prompt and type ipconfig /flushdns.

Comment: Thanks. I apologize - I overlooked your response.
The problem was the non www version of the domain wasn't assigned to the site.